# Converting CSV into Flare JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I am trying to convert csv data into Json with parent and child relationship for my python application.
The csv file contain Genesymbol and disease name. Based on the Gene symbol am converting it into Child. The sample csv file

```
gene,disease
A1BG,Adenocarcinoma
A1BG,apnea
A1BG,Athritis
A2M,Asthma
A2M,Astrocytoma
A2M,Diabetes
NAT1,polyps
NAT1,lymphoma
NAT1,neoplasms
```

The output Json contains like this format. Please let me know any changes required to get desired output.

```
{
     "name": "A1BG",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Adenocarcinoma", "size": 2138},
      {"name": "apnea", "size": 3824},
      {"name": "Athritis", "size": 1353}
      ]
    },

{
     "name": "A2M",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Asthma", "size": 2138},
      {"name": "Astrocytoma", "size": 3824},
      {"name": "Diabetes", "size": 1353}
      ]
    },


{
     "name": "NAT1",
     "children": [
      {"name": "polyps", "size": 2138},
      {"name": "lymphoma", "size": 3824},
      {"name": "neoplasms", "size": 1353}
      ]
    }
```

The python code i have written is

```
from itertools import groupby 
from collections import OrderedDict
import json    

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
        
finalList = []
finalDict = {}
grouped = df.groupby(['gene'])
for key, value in grouped:


    dictionary = {}

    j = grouped.get_group(key).reset_index(drop=True)
    dictionary['gene'] = j.at[0, 'gene']
    

    dictList = []
    anotherDict = {}
    for i in j.index:

        anotherDict['disese'] = j.at[i, 'disease']
        

        dictList.append(anotherDict)

    dictionary['children'] = dictList


    finalList.append(dictionary)

import json
json.dumps(finalList)
```

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like this:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd


result = (
    df
    .groupby("gene", as_index=False).agg(list)
    .rename(columns={"gene": "name", "disease": "children"})
    .to_dict("records")
)

with open('output.json', "w") as out:
    json.dump(result, out, indent=4)
```

---

```json
[
    {
        "name": "A1BG",
        "children": [
            "Adenocarcinoma",
            "apnea",
            "Athritis"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "A2M",
        "children": [
            "Asthma",
            "Astrocytoma",
            "Diabetes"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "NAT1",
        "children": [
            "polyps",
            "lymphoma",
            "neoplasms"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Json data should be in the same format becuase it is input for other appplication

Comment: I don't think it would result in a valid JSON @venkat_SAI